# How to use database/sql library without any external driver libraries as a local file-type database. The same way how Python has sqlite3

Tags: database, go

so I was trying to find how could I use use a database with golang with the database/sql library. I saw many blogs and videos but was unable to find how to use the database/sql library without using some external library.

Some tutorials only showed how to connect to a SQL database with a connection (which uses the username and password based authentication to connect to the database), whereas I wanted to use a sqlite3 like file type database connection such that I am able to connect to the database as a file in the current directory.

I don't want to use any external libraries and want to know if there is a way to do the same using just the in-built libraries of Golang.

None of the tutorials were helping me as all of them used some kind of libraries which they imported.

Comment: https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql@go1.21.1 says *"The sql package __must be used in conjunction with a database driver__. See https://golang.org/s/sqldrivers for a list of drivers."*

Comment: If you don't want an external driver you can write your own.

Comment: @mkopriva Is there any way I can use a database with Golang with or without the database/sql library without using any external libraries. I dont require the database to be a SQL database. A key val database would also work.

Comment: If you don't care about SQL and you don't want to use an external dependency you can simply write the data into a file using whatever format you prefer. And for in memory kv store use a `map.`

Comment: I fail to quite parse your question. Are you basically asking about whether there's a support for any so-called "embedded database" in the [Go's standard library](https://pkg.go.dev/std)? If yes, then the answer is no, there is not.

Comment: If you're asking whether there's _any_ way to use an embedded database (such as SQLite) in Go, and «I don't want to use any external libraries» means you do not want to set up any separate piece of software–which is a database engine–to run the actual database, then yes, there's a host of high-quality third-party packages for Go which implement almost anything you can think of in an embedded manner–meaning the retulting execulatbe image file produced from your program won't have any external dependencies.

Comment: If you're asking about using SQLite in particular, there exist multiple packages to wrap the SQLite's stock C library, and also a wonderful [`gitlab.com/cznic/sqlite`](https://gitlab.com/cznic/sqlite/) which is a C-to-Go source-code translation which implements SQLite in pure Go.

Comment: For a non-SQL K/V embedded DB you can look at <https://github.com/dgraph-io/badger> and BoltDB for a start.

Comment: @kostix Thank you for your suggestions and help. Though my needs are a bit different. Thank you for helping, appreciated.

Comment: «my needs are a bit different»–you might want to elaborate then ;-) If you really mean not depending on 3rd-party code, there's a sort of solution to this called "vendoring", when basically you "import" such 3rd-party packages under a special directory in your own code base (and commit into a version control system etc). Essentially, this code works as your "own". This approach is widely used in industrial software engineering, and Go tooling has special support for this.

Comment: @kostix I just made my own database in Golang now; Thanks for helping me!